# How do i solve the permission denied rStudio error

Tags: r, csv, file, save

I am trying to create text and csv files, from dataframes and I have received the same error message, I have checked all possible administrator permissions and folder permissions, working directory but nothing works.

```
setwd("C:\\Users\\#####\\Documents\\RScripts\\Cap05")
getwd()
[1] "C:/Users/Mohamad/Documents/RScripts/Cap05"

write.table(mtcars, file = "mtcars2.txt", sep = "|", col.names = T, qmethod = "double")
```

> Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
> cannot open the connection
> In addition: Warning message:
> In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
> cannot open file 'mtcars2.txt': Permission denied

Comment: after your `setdir; getdir` code, please try `dir()` to confirm that there is a file there called mtcars2.txt.   If there is,  please go to that directory and try to open the file from Windows File explorer.

Comment: I finally solved the problem, the antivirus was blocking rStudio from making changes to my folders even though it had permissions to do so